# Calling functions within other functions outside

Tags: javascript

I've used this ability previously but for some reason, it isn't working and is giving the error below. I am not sure why and it is probably something obviously wrong that I am not seeing.

```
TypeError: (intermediate value).inside is not a function
```

Caller is called and runs a new outside function which specifically targets the inside function to run alone leaving the rest of the outside function none of the wiser about inner running.

```
function caller() {
new outside().inside();
}


(function outside() {
function inside() {...}
})();

caller();
```

Preferably `outside()` would be a self invoking function, but I don't think that is even possible.

Comment: This code can't have worked. Also, `outside` isn't even defined in your snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function declared inside another function *creates a local variable in the scope of that function*, it does not create a *property on the return value of the function*.

If you want the latter, then you have to create it explicitly.

Also note, since you are using the `new` keyword, that constructor functions are expected to be named with an initial capital letter.

```js
function caller() {
  new Outside().inside();
}


function Outside() {
  function inside() {
    console.log("Inside");
  }

  this.inside = inside;
}

caller();
```

Comment: Also, if `inside` doesn't reference any of the local variables of `Outside`, it's more efficient to define the function on `Outside.prototype`